# OnPreferenceClickListener, how to use it

Tags: java, android

I'm using the following code

```js
public class prefs extends PreferenceActivity implements OnPreferenceClickListener {
  
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
 }

 @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference pref) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     System.out.println("hereiam");
        
        if (pref.getKey().equals("p_developer")) {
        
        } else {
            
        }
        return true;
    } 
}
```

It looks like the onPreferenceClick is never called. What I am doing wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: As an unrelated note, don't use `System.out.println` for debugging, use `LogCat`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to set your activity as a listener to your preference clicks. Add this to your activity's onCreate:

```
**your preference**.setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);
```

Comment: Thanks. I see... is there a way to do this for all the preferences in one shot?